# CABasicAnimation - animationDidStop not called

Tags: caanimation

I am making a CABasicAnimation and the problem is that the animationDidStop delegate method does not get called. I am not sure why but hopefully someone knows.

Here is my animation:

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
theAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform.translation.x"];
theAnimation.duration = 54; 
//theAnimation.repeatCount = 6;
theAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES; 

theAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (self.myImageView.frame.size.height / 5) + (self.view.frame.size.height - self.myImageView.center.x)];
theAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 6.0 - (self.myImageView.frame.origin.y + self.myImageView.frame.size.height)];

//[self.myImageView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey: @"animateLayer"];
[theAnimation setValue:@"Animation1" forKey:@"animateLayer"];
[[self.myImageView layer] addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:nil];
```

Also here is my animationDidStop method:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CABasicAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {

    NSString* value = [theAnimation valueForKey:@"animateLayer"];
    if ([value isEqualToString:@"Animation1"])
    {
        [self themethod];
        return;
    }


    if ([value isEqualToString:@"Animation2"])
    {
        [self themethod];
        return;
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set delegate to call `animationDidStop`.

```
theAnimation.delegate = class (self)
```

Comment: __Be aware that `CAAnimation`'s `delegate` is strong, so you might need to set it to `nil` to avoid retain cycles!__

Comment: Thanks, but in 2011 "strong" probably not yet implemented... :)

Comment: I know, it was for other people that would come across this, as I learned it the hard way and didn't see it mention anywhere on the internet :(